# How do I get all files in a folder that start with a particular string?

Tags: c#, file

How do I get all files in a folder that start with a particular string?

For example, say I have a folder with these three files:

```
Family01
Family02
Family03
NotFamily04
```

How do I get just the first three files, that start with the string "Family"?

I've used

```
DirectoryInfo d = new DirectoryInfo(@"C:\Users\H2 Software PC\Documents\Family\");
FileInfo[] Files = d.GetFiles(????);
```

But I don't know what to put in my `FileInfo[]`.

Comment: Are you asking how to get all the files whose name begins with "Family"?

Comment: Your example is confusing. Do "Family" and "Fam" have the "same name"?

Comment: `d.GetFiles("Family*");` ?

Comment: No. Family and Fam are different.

Comment: Thanks.It do work. d.GetFiles("Family*");

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the static method of the `Directory` class.

```
var files = Directory.GetFiles(path, "ini*");
```

this will return all files starting with `ini`.

You don't need the `DirectoryInfo`.

Comment: I do need to use DirectoryInfo inable for me to merge those files using for each

Answer (score 5):

Option one would be to use wildcards (this would be the better choice):

```
FileInfo[] Files = d.GetFiles("Family*");
```

The second option would be to use LINQ, though it would be less efficient:

```
FileInfo[] Files = d.GetFiles().Where(x => x.StartsWith("Family")).ToArray();
```